# Access PostgreSQL server from LAN

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've been trying to edit pg_hba.conf file in order to be able to access the server using just the IP address with, so far, no success.

For example, I can access using «localhost», but I want to access using the IP address that my router gave me which is something like 192.168.1.X

This is mi pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

Any help?

Comment: There are several pieces of info that are needed. You router is giving you a LAN IP so you won't be able to access your machine from outside your LAN. I am not familiar with PostgreSQL but I know that MySQL on Ubuntu requires that I restart the MySQL service on Ubuntu. What OS are you using? And finally, do you have a firewall running that would prevent access to the port PostgreSQL uses?

Comment: I don't have a firewall and I'm aware that it could only be accessed by LAN. I'm using Linux 3.12 (Manjaro) @gabe

Comment: @simon Just wanted to make sure you were aware of the LAN constraint since your title said everywhere. Sorry I can't be more help but I use Ubuntu and MySQL. I would suggest you add the PostgreSQL and OS to your question so that people looking to help you in the future don't miss it. Good luck.

Comment: It would be rather helpful if you actually showed your `pg_hba.conf`. Also, what is `listen_addresses` set to in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: @CraigRinger edited to add pg_hba.conf

Comment: I had trouble connecting to my postgresql db with pgAdmin4 and it turned out to be because I was stuck with an old version (Ubuntu). Had to add the postgres repo. This probably wasn't your issue but others might end up here try to troubleshoot the same problem I had =)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

First, edit the postgresql.conf file, and set [listen_addresses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES). The default value of 'localhost' will only listen on the loopback adaptor. You can change it to '*', meaning listen on all addresses, or specifically list the IP address of the interfaces you want it to accept connections from. Note that this is the IP address which the interface has allocated to it, which you can see using `ifconfig` or `ip addr` commands.

You must restart postgresql for the changes to listen_addresses to take effect.

Next, in [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), you will need an entry like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    {dbname}        {user}          192.168.1.0/24          md5
```

{dbname} is the database name you are allowing access to. You can put "all" for all databases.

{user} is the user who is allowed to connect. Note that this is the postgresql user, not necessarily the unix user.

The ADDRESS part is the network address and mask that you want to allow. The mask I specified will work for 192.168.1.x as you requested.

The METHOD part is the authentication method to use. There are a number of options there. md5 means it will use an md5 hashed password. 'trust' which you had in your sample means no authentication at all - this is definitely not recommended.

Changes to pg_hba.conf will take effect after reloading the server. You can to this using `pg_ctl reload` (or via the init scripts, depending on your OS distro).

Comment: Actually you only need a `pg_ctl reload` to have it take effect, not a full restart. Or `SELECT pg_reload_conf()`.

Comment: @CraigRinger the restart is required for listen_addresses (manual says "This parameter can only be set at server start."). As I stated there pg_hba can be changed via reload.

Comment: I was missing the postgresql.conf part. Thanks.

Comment: Easy way to restart Postgres installed by Homebrew is: `brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: Just installed Postgresql 13.3 with standard steps and the default value for listen_addresses is '*', not localhost.

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu `sudo service postgresql reload` see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156722/215358