# How to connect to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, rust

I want to connect to a PostgreSQL server with [`rust-postgres`](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres):

```
let mut client = Client::connect("host=localhost user=postgres", NoTls)?;
```

The complete code example is from [`Client`](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.17.0/postgres/struct.Client.html#example) and [`Config`](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.17.0/postgres/config/struct.Config.html).

I keep getting the error

```
Error: Error { kind: Connect, cause: Some(Os { code: 111, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }) }
```

In a terminal, I can interact with PostgreSQL:

```
(base) wm@wm:~/Desktop/HP$ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@wm:~$ psql
psql (10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

There are few issues relevant to failed connections, so I guess there must be something I missed.

Comment: Why do you have spaces in `user = postgres`?

Comment: @mcarton I corrected it

Comment: Are you running your application with `sudo` as you do with `psql`?

Comment: @mcarton No, I want to run it without `sudo`

Comment: @mcarton Does this mean I need to create a user to run `psql` without `sudo`, then make the connection?

Comment: It seems likely that one path is using a Unix socket and the other is using a TCP socket, but you haven't configured your Postgres server to allow TCP connections from that user.

Comment: @Shepmaster I will do more lookups to understand your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql supports client connections via local Unix sockets or via TCP/IP connections.

In the default configuration, though, it will not listen for TCP/IP connections. It will only listen for connections to a local Unix socket. The location of this socket is defined by the postgresql configuration variable `unix_socket_directories`.

In your tests, you have found that when running the `psql` command line tool with no arguments, it manages to connect to the database. This works because `psql` uses the postgresql supplied client library (`libpq`) and this client library has the default behavior of connecting to the local Unix socket if no hostname is supplied.

However, when using `rust-postgres`, you are supplying a connection string including the text "`host=localhost`". This is instructing `rust-postgres` to make a connection to IP address `localhost`. It fails because the postgresql server is not configured to listen on any IP interfaces, and only listen on a Unix socket.

You could change the connection string to specify the unix socket to connect to, for example:

```
host=/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

The value above reflects where the socket is on my machine, it might be different on yours.

The `libpq` library allows you to leave the `host` parameter out altogether and it will connect to the Unix socket automatically; unfortunately it does not look like `rust-postgres` supports this though.

Alternatively, you could reconfigure your postgresql server so that it listens on the loopback IP adapter. This involves setting the `listen_addresses` parameter in the postgresl configuration file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22083740/1411457) for more details, including changes you will need to make to the authentication in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, I don't know what the value might be on my machine, I tried with your value, and I get `Error: Error { kind: Connect, cause: Some(Os { code: 20, kind: Other, message: "Not a directory" }) }`

Comment: first I add `listen_addresses = '*'  ` to `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`, then I execute `sudo service postgresql restart`,  then I add `local   all             postgres        localhost               md5` to `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf`, with `let mut client = Client::connect("host=localhost user=postgres", NoTls)?;`, I still got the error    `Error: Error { kind: Connect, cause: Some(Os { code: 111, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }) }`

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon you might also need to check firewall settings